# Convert array to nested hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have following array

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How to convert it to hash like this bellow:

```
{'a' => { position: index of array element a }, 'b' ...., 'c' ... }
```

Best regards
Georgi.

Comment: When you ask for code, we expect you to show your attempt(s) to solve the problem. Failing to do so makes it look like you're just fishing for someone else to write it for you.

Comment: Thank you for critic. In future i will add attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: @Georgi - Thank you for responding positively to feedback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you could create an array like the following using the methods `Array#map` and `Enumerator#with_index`:

```
ary = ['a', 'b', 'c']
temporary = ary.map.with_index { |e, i| [e, { position: i }] }
# => [["a", {:position=>0}], ["b", {:position=>1}], ["c", {:position=>2}]]
```

Then you can convert the resulting array to hash using the [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) method available since Ruby 2.1:

```
temporary.to_h
# => {"a"=>{:position=>0}, "b"=>{:position=>1}, "c"=>{:position=>2}}
```

For older versions of Ruby, the [`Hash.[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) method will do:

```
Hash[temporary]
# => {"a"=>{:position=>0}, "b"=>{:position=>1}, "c"=>{:position=>2}}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the new Array#to_h, good riddance to the ugly Hash[...].

Comment: thank you. very well explained

Answer (score 1):

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].each_with_index.reduce({}) do |s, (e, i)|
  s[e] = { position: i }
  s
end
```